# Trouble With 'Scope' of Angular Controller In Electron App

Tags: angularjs, logging, electron

Background: I have a gui I'm putting together for an application I've been working on. The app loads its last state from a YAML file, and is supposed to save that state to the YAML file when the app closes. I'm using the following event listener...

```
// Handle close event
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
    if(doc) {
        // This line gives error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: main is not defined"
        doc.project_notes.text = main.summernoteText;
        fs.writeFile('../resources/project.yml', yaml.safeDump(doc), function (error) {
            if (error) {
                throw error
            }
        });
    }

    console.log("Bye...");
});

angular
    .module('inspinia')
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
```

(and in my index.html)

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
```

I'm saving all of the states in a global variable called `doc`. It loads the yml file just fine using the following

```
function MainCtrl() {

    activeProject = LoadActiveProject();

    /**
     * summernoteText - used for Summernote plugin
     */
    this.summernoteText = doc.project_notes.text;

};
```

My issue is primarily with scope of the angular controller/variables.

First, am I handling this correctly in general?
If this is reasonable, how can I update doc.project_notes.text from my unload function OR link the two variables by reference?

I'm pretty new to Javascript.

Comment: Try using $rootScope. This is a parent of $scope in angularJs, You can set the value in your controller like $rootScope.summernoteText = doc.project_notes.text. You can access it using $rootScope.summernoteText anywhere in your angular. See if this helps.

Comment: @SiddheshPhatak I got `"Uncaught ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined"`. I think the problem is that my EventListener is part of window, not in angular